# SonarQube is unable to start on CentOS: systemd returns (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Tags: centos, sonarqube, startup

Following https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-sonarqube-on-centos-7 to install SonarQube on my CentOS. 
When I'm trying to start the SonarQube via `sudo systemctl start sonar` it is giving below error:

```
Job for sonar.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status sonar.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Output of systemctl status sonar.service:

```
sonar.service - SonarQube service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sonar.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Wed 2019-04-24 16:56:39 UTC; 19s ago
  Process: 23573 ExecStart=/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Apr 24 16:56:39 ip-172-31-13-96.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: sonar.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
Apr 24 16:56:39 ip-172-31-13-96.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start SonarQube service.
Apr 24 16:56:39 ip-172-31-13-96.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit sonar.service entered failed state.
Apr 24 16:56:39 ip-172-31-13-96.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: sonar.service failed.
Apr 24 16:56:39 ip-172-31-13-96.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: sonar.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 24 16:56:39 ip-172-31-13-96.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for sonar.service
Apr 24 16:56:39 ip-172-31-13-96.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start SonarQube service.
Apr 24 16:56:39 ip-172-31-13-96.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit sonar.service entered failed state.
Apr 24 16:56:39 ip-172-31-13-96.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: sonar.service failed.
```

Output of journalctl -xe:

```
Apr 24 16:56:39 ip-172-31-13-96.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting SonarQube service...
-- Subject: Unit sonar.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit sonar.service has begun starting up.
Apr 24 16:56:39 ip-172-31-13-96.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[23573]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sona
-- Subject: Process /opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- The process /opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh could not be executed and failed.
--
-- The error number returned by this process is 2.
Apr 24 16:56:39 ip-172-31-13-96.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: sonar.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
Apr 24 16:56:39 ip-172-31-13-96.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start SonarQube service.
-- Subject: Unit sonar.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit sonar.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Apr 24 16:56:39 ip-172-31-13-96.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit sonar.service entered failed state.
Apr 24 16:56:39 ip-172-31-13-96.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: sonar.service failed.
Apr 24 16:56:39 ip-172-31-13-96.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: sonar.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 24 16:56:39 ip-172-31-13-96.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for sonar.service
Apr 24 16:56:39 ip-172-31-13-96.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start SonarQube service.
-- Subject: Unit sonar.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit sonar.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Apr 24 16:56:39 ip-172-31-13-96.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit sonar.service entered failed state.
Apr 24 16:56:39 ip-172-31-13-96.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: sonar.service failed.
```

Comment: I also have this issue, how did you solve it? In my case, the ExecStart command are able to run successfully in terminal

Answer (score 0):

`status=203/EXEC` means that `systemd` cannot execute `ExecStart` script. The most "popular" reasons are:

- incorrect path to script
- script has invalid permissions:

  - service user does not have permission to read script
  - script is not marked as executable

I hope `/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh` exists, so please verify that the script is marked as executable.